# How to load a game using file/object input stream

Tags: java, serialization, load, deserialization, objectinputstream

I have written save / Load methods (not sure entirely if the save works but the file 'minesweepersavestate.ser' appears in my project folder after calling `saveGame()`). I want to try to get the load to work because at current it doesn't seem to do anything.

Here are my functions:

```
   public void saveGame(){

        GameBoard b = new GameBoard();
        try {
            System.out.println("Creating File/Object output stream...");
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("minesweepersavestate.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

            System.out.println("Writing GameBoard Object...");
            out.writeObject(b);

            System.out.println("Save Successful...\n");
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();

        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("no");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("no");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }


    public void loadBoard()
    {
        GameBoard b = null;
        try {

            System.out.println("Creating File/Object input stream...");

            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("minesweepersavestate.ser");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

            System.out.println("Loading GameBoard Object...");
            b = (GameBoard)in.readObject();

            System.out.println("Load Successful...\n");
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Class not found\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How can I alter this method so that when i call the `loadBoard()` method, it brings back the game in the state it was saved?

Edit:

GameBoard Class:

```
public class GameBoard extends JFrame implements Serializable
{
//MENU ITEMS
private JFrame frame;
private JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
private JTable table;

//FIELDS USED FOR GAMEPLAY
private int x;
private int y;
private boolean mineTrue;
private boolean triedTrue;
private static int boardsize = 8; 
private  int numberOfMines = 10;
public static final int Empty = 0;
public static final int Mine = -1;
public static final int Flag = -2;
public static final int FMine = -3;
public static final int RevealedMine = -4;
public static final int RevealedEmpty = -5;
// SIZE OF BUTTONS
private int gridsize = 45;
// ARRAY FOR THE BUTTONS
private JButton[][] buttons;
private int[][] board;
//VARIABLE USED FOR LABELS
private static int noGamesPlayed = 0;
private static int noGamesWon = 0;
private int mine = 10;
private int minesLeft = 10;
private static int score = 1;
private static String playername;
// GAME STATUS
private boolean gamegoing = true;
// GAME LABELS

private JLabel space = new JLabel("");
private JTextField nameEnter = new JTextField("Enter name here: ");
private JButton saveName = new JButton("Play");
private JLabel namelabel = new JLabel("Player 1: ");
private JLabel scorelabel = new JLabel("0 points ");
private JLabel status = new JLabel("Game in Progress: ");
private JLabel gamesPlayed = new JLabel("Games Played: " + noGamesPlayed);
private JLabel gamesWon = new JLabel("Games Won : " + noGamesWon);
private JLabel noMines = new JLabel("Number of Mines: " + minesLeft);


/**
 * Constructor 
 */
public GameBoard() { }

/**
 *Making the game Frame
 */
private void makeFrame() { }

// MAKING THE GAME MENU BAR
public void makeMenuBar(){  
}   

public void setx(int pmeter) { }

public void sety(int pmeter) { }

public int getx() { }

public int gety() { }

public void settried(boolean paramBoolean) { }

public boolean gettried() { }

public void setmine(boolean paramBoolean) { }

public boolean getmine() { }

//ASSIGN MINES TO RANDOM LOCATION
public void assignmines() { }

// *********************************GAME CONTROLS************
private void quit() { }

//RESETS THE BOARD
public void reset() { }    

public void newGame() { }

public void biggerBoard() { }

public void changeDifficulty() { }

public void saveGame() { }


public void loadBoard() { }

// LOSING THE GAME ALERT
public void lose() { }

// WINNING THE GAME ALERT
public void win() { }

// UPDATING THE SCORE
public void updatescore() { }

public void gamesPlayed() { }

public void UpdateName() { }

public void updateGamesPlayed() { }

public void updateGamesWon() { }

//WHAT VALUES THE CHARACTER HAVE
static char whichCharacter(int value) { }

//This method shows how many mines are around the spot that was clicked
static int minesAround(int[][] board, int row, int col) { }

// This method takes in an x and y value and defines what should happen when the user clicks there. 
public void click(int rows, int cols) { }

//ACTION WHEN USER CLICKS ON A BUTTON INNER CLASS
private class MouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;

    public MouseListener(int row, int col) { }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { }

}
```

}

Comment: Do you get any Exception when you load it? Or is b just null?

Comment: Can you provide an outline of the code for your GameBoard object? Class declaration, fields, and method signatures?

Comment: Edited. Actually i just checked now the save isn't working i Just got the error:Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at GameBoard.click(GameBoard.java:434)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that all your fields in your class are `Serializable` as [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) suggests.  Of particular note are the requirements for a class to be `Serializable`:

> Notice that for a class to be serialized successfully, two conditions must be met:
>
> The class must implement the java.io.Serializable interface.
>
> All of the fields in the class must be serializable. If a field is not serializable, it must be marked transient.

This means you'll have to do some digging in the Javadocs for all the fields in your `GameBoard` class.  For instance, I did a quick search on `JFrame`, and there seems to be a bit of a [nuance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567033/serializing-a-jframe-and-sending-via-network) when it comes to 
saving a `JFrame`.  When you retrieve the state of your saved game, it might be better just to recreate the GUI from scratch rather than to rely upon `Serialization` to do it for you.  [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712001/restore-previously-serialized-jframe-object-how) also seems to concur that it's not a good idea to rely on Java to restore a GUI for you, but gives a suggestion as to how to possibly make it work:

> once deserialised, you will need to show the frame with `frame.setVisible(true);`